# SQL: Using LN vs LOG function

Tags: sql, postgresql, performance, optimization

I would like to know if there might be any difference performance-wise comparing the following functions used in an SQL query:

- `LN(x)`: natural logarithm
- `LOG(x)`: logarithm with base 10
- `LOG(x, b)`: logarithm with base *b*, e.g. 2

When I have a formula which I can express using any of the above, which one is the best to use?

My focus would be on PostgreSQL, but any info on others or general considerations are much appreciated.

Comment: Race your horses... https://ericlippert.com/2012/12/17/performance-rant/

Comment: I don't know my way around [the Postgres source code](https://git.postgresql.org/gitweb/?p=postgresql.git;a=tree) to prove it, but I would bet that either a) all three are implemented with C standard library functions; or b) the first two actually delegate to the third. Either way, the differences in performance of such low-level functions are going to measure in the microseconds at most, so are likely to be **completely imperceptible** in basically any real-world scenario.

Comment: As @jarlh says you should run and time the queries. Now, I would guess the cost of preprocessing the query and accessing the data (I/O) and returning the result (network cost) is far higher that the CPU cost of computing a logarithm. Anyway, run and compare.

Comment: You can simply try: `explain (analyze) select ln(42) from generate_series(1,10e6);` vs. `explain (analyze) select log(42) from generate_series(1,10e6);` ...

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name Good idea in principle, but the optimizer will already execute immutable functions on constants. Perhaps `log((SELECT 42))` will do.

Comment: @LaurenzAlbe Or feed it the output of the series?

Comment: I suggest which performs better is **completely irrelevant** as given exactly the same input, they return totally different results. Thus they are not comparable..  Correct results overrides performance every time.